# Android ShareActionProvider failed to share to Facebook

Tags: android, android-intent, shareactionprovider

I try to use ShareActionProvider (`support.v7`) to perform sharing for my app. All apps, such as Gmail, Evernote, et. al, work fine - except Facebook. I don't know what the problem is. Here is my code snipet:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.share, menu);
    MenuItem shareItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);
     mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(shareItem);
    mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent());

    return true;
}

public Intent shareIntent () {
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("type/plain");
    shareIntent.setType("image/*");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"SUBJECT");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"TEXT TEXT");
    return shareIntent;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, do not call `setType()` twice, as the second one will replace the first one.

Second, `type/plain` is not a valid MIME type. Try `text/plain`.

Third, if you are going to use `image/*`, you need to use `EXTRA_STREAM` to provide the image.

Comment: thanks very much, you save me an hour!! About sharing a image to facebook, can I use an external link like "http://www.abc.com/abc.png"?

Comment: @user2761885: Usually sharing is for local content. I cannot speak to whether Facebook supports sharing of links this way.